# Java HashSet elements do not re-arrange themselves when there hashes change

Tags: java, collections

```
import java.util.*;
class KeyMaster {
    public int i;
    public KeyMaster(int i) { this.i = i; }
    public boolean equals(Object o) { return i == ((KeyMaster)o).i; }
    public int hashCode() { return i; }
}

public class MapIt {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Set<KeyMaster> set = new HashSet<KeyMaster>();
        KeyMaster k1 = new KeyMaster(1);
        KeyMaster k2 = new KeyMaster(2);
        set.add(k1); set.add(k1);
        set.add(k2); set.add(k2);
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
        k2.i = 1;
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
            set.remove(k1);
        System.out.print(set.size() + “:”);
        set.remove(k2);
        System.out.print(set.size());
     }
  }
```

What is the result?

```
A. 4:4:2:2
C. 2:2:1:0
E. 2:1:0:0
G. 4:3:2:1
B. 4:4:3:2
D. 2:2:0:0
F. 2:2:1:1
Answer: F
```

Can anybody explain the answer. My doubt is this. K2's i changed but set still has 2 elements one of which i think still refers to the object referred by changed k2. so why doesnt remove(k2) works?

Comment: There is no `F` option in the answers you've given.  What?!  (In any event, modifying the elements in a `Set` after you've added them can have _completely_ undefined behavior.)

Comment: the output is always F

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Values are only hashed when they are added to the set, changing the result of the hash will not cause the value to be rehashed in the collection.

So assume your HashSet has two bucket, one where the hashcode is 1 and the other where the hashcode is 2, when you add them k1 will go in bucket 1 and k2 will go in bucket two.

When you change k2s value to 1 it does not re-arrange itself in the HashSet.

When you attempt to remove k2 it hashes to bucket 1 because of the value of i, since nothing in the bucket matches (as you've already removed k1) nothing is removed.

[HashSet#remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) returns a boolean if anything was removed; if you print that you will see your removal of k2 did not occur.